# Remove duplicate from custom ArrayList by parameter

Tags: java, android, arraylist

I'm facing a problem that I don't arrive to resolve:

I read an `ArrayList` from the phone:

```
ArrayList<Game> gameResult = writeRead.getArrayList(this);
```

I put the object `gamer` from each `game` in a new `ArrayList`:

```
ArrayList<Gamer> gamerList = new ArrayList<>();
for (int i = 0; i < gameResult.size(); i++) {
    gamerList.add(gameResult.get(i).getWinnerGamer());
}
```

now, what I would like is to:

- add `Gamer` in an `ArrayList` if not already present
- if present, add ++ to a parameter named `LeaderPoints`
- sort by point

It's about a leaderboard activity with a custom `ArrayList`, but I don't arrive to do it.

All my code:

```
private void setGamerList() {

    ArrayList<Game> gameResult = writeRead.getArrayList(this);
    ArrayList<Gamer> gamerList = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<Gamer> gamerNoDuplicate = new ArrayList<>();

    if (gameResult != null) {

        for (int i = 0; i < gameResult.size(); i++) {
            gamerList.add(gameResult.get(i).getWinnerGamer());
        }
    }

    Log.i(TAG, "--------------------------------");

    Collections.sort(mGamerList, (o1, o2) ->
        o2.getLeaderboardScore().compareTo(o1.getLeaderboardScore()));
}
```

Comment: can you show the `Gamer` class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
writeRead.getArrayList(this).stream()
            .map(Game::getWinnerGamer)
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Gamer::getName, Collectors.summingInt(Gamer::getLeaderboardScore)))
            .entrySet()
            .stream()
            .sorted(Comparator.comparing(Map.Entry<String, Integer>::getValue).reversed())
            .map(entry -> new Gamer(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue()))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Steps:

1. extract winner
2. group winners by name and sum their scores. As result you will get Map
3. get entrySet of this Map
4. open stream on this entySet
5. sort by scores in DESC direction
6. map entry to Gamer (create new gamer instance for each entry)
7. collect to list

My answer based on assumption that you have such structure :

```
class Game {
    private Gamer winnerGamer;
    // getter & setter
}

class Gamer {
    private String name;
    private Integer leaderboardScore;
    // getters & setters && AllArgsContructor
}
```

BTW: if you override equals and hash code in class Gamer you can avoid Gamer recreation with this:

```
writeRead.getArrayList(this).stream()
            .map(Game::getWinnerGamer)
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(), Collectors.summingInt(Gamer::getLeaderboardScore)))
            .entrySet()
            .stream()
            .sorted(Comparator.comparing(Map.Entry<Gamer, Integer>::getValue).reversed())
            .map(Map.Entry::getKey)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: you are welcome :) Streams help us not to write redundant code ;)

Answer (score 1):

Override **equals and hashCode methods** of your Gamer object class.

Then before adding object to ArrayList, check `Arraylist.contains()`, if yes then you can either call `ArrayList.indexOf()` method to get that object instance in `ArrayList`, increment the value of LeaderPoints and call `ArrayList.set()` to set back the instance at the same position.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `Set` Instead of `ArrayList` for unique value.

**override HashCode and Equal Method**.

```
Set<Gamer> gamerNoDuplicate=new HashSet();
if (gameResult != null) {
    for (int i = 0; i < gameResult.size(); i++) {
        if(gamerNoDuplicate.contains(gameResult.get(i).getWinnerGamer()){
            Gamer alreadyExist = gamerNoDuplicate.indexOf(gameResult.get(i).getWinnerGamer());
            alreadyExist.setLeaderPoints(alreadyExist.getLeaderPoints()+ gameResult.get(i).getWinnerGamer().getLeaderPoints());
        }else{
            gamerNoDuplicate.add(gameResult.get(i).getWinnerGamer());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Look good ! but i got a error on indexOf ... i don't know why ?

Answer (score 0):

Finally i did it like this :

and it work perfectly
Thanks !

```
if (gameResult != null) {


        for (int i = 0; i < gameResult.size(); i++) {
            gamerList.add(gameResult.get(i).getWinnerGamer());
        }

        /* --------- */


        for (int i = 0; i < gamerList.size(); i++) {
            Gamer gamer = gamerList.get(i);
            gamer.setLeaderboardScore(1);
            boolean isInArray = false;

            if (!gamerNoDuplicate.isEmpty()) {
                for (int j = 0; j < gamerNoDuplicate.size(); j++) {
                    if (gamer.getName().equals(gamerNoDuplicate.get(j).getName())) {
                        gamerNoDuplicate.get(j).addLeaderscorePoint();
                        isInArray = true;
                    }
                }

                if (!isInArray) {
                    gamerNoDuplicate.add(gamer);
                }

            } else gamerNoDuplicate.add(gamer);
        }
    }
```